# Как оформить запрос в mySQL в ActiveRecord?

Tags: mysql, sql, yii2

Есть такой запрос:

```
SELECT id, name_film, created_at
FROM `fl_films`
UNION
SELECT id, name_serial, created_at
FROM `fl_serial`
ORDER BY created_at DESC
LIMIT 0 , 20
```

Как мне оформить его в `ActiveRecord`, чтобы потом использовать связи моделей этих таблиц.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данной задаче https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/7992 обсуждается использование UNION при составлении запроса к БД.

Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23285483/how-create-query-with-union-two-select-in-yii) также обсуждается UNION в Yii2

Answer (score 0):

Решается вопрос тяжело но решается итак модель

```
<?php

namespace common\models;
use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "fl_actours".
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $name
 * @property string $biography
 */
class FilmsFordate extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'fl_filmsFordate';
    }
}?>
```

Контролер

```
            Yii::$app->db->createCommand(" CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW fl_filmsFordate(id,name,created_at) AS  SELECT id, name_film, created_at FROM `fl_films`
UNION SELECT id, name_serial, created_at FROM `fl_serial` ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 0 , 20");
        $last= FilmsFordate::find()->all();
```

правда с вязи надо обновить, а так все все работает. Очень сильно помогла эта [статья](http://www.elisdn.ru/blog/44/multitable-search-for-yii-site) . Всем спасибо.